# Opening link in new tab from Polymer Modal

Tags: javascript, html, css, polymer

Hi just a very simple question. I have a Modal in my Polymer 3 page. I want to add a link in the model and open the link in new Tab, but its not working. The link opens in the same window, where the popup is opened?

```html
<html>
  <div class="modal--innerContainer">
     <div>
        <h3>${item.title}</h3>
        <p>${item.content}</p>
        <a href="#" target="_blank">Read more</a>
     </div>
     <button on-click="${() => this._closeModal()}">Close</button>
  </div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try this

```html
<html>
<div class="modal--innerContainer">
    <div>
        <h3>${item.title}</h3>
        <p>${item.content}</p>
        <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="http://www.google.com">Read More</a>

    </div>
    <button on-click="${() => this._closeModal()}">Close</button>
</div>

</html>
```

Comment: No problem dude :) please close the question by marking correct if it helped.

Answer (score 1):

**Try adding this line. It works!**

```
<a href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/5/5e/Gothiccover.png" target="_blank">Read more</a>
```

Comment: I already have that target = _blank. This link is in the Modal and it opens the new link in the same page where the popup is opened.

Comment: It's working for me. It would be helpful if you can send an entire code (which includes parent page and popup model code)

Comment: It actually need rel="noopener noreferrer" in anchor tag